# SQL Server combine data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one containing an ID number and a DateTime (MAIN TABLE). The other table has an ID, LocationName and DateTime (Location table).

The DateTime in the main table is a frequent capture of automated signals. The DateTime in the location table is when an object has been moved to a new location. Both the IDs are the primary key and link.

What I'm trying to do is produce just one table showing when the location changes occur, showing ID, DateTime from the main table and LocationName from the location table.

I have been trying for hours but can't seem to do it...

Below is an example of the tables and the end result..

Any help would be grateful.

Thanks

```
MAIN TABLE           Location Table

ID DateTime          ID DateTime         Location 
-----------------    ----------------------------
1  20200101 12:00    1  20200101 11:45   Loc 1
1  20200101 13:00    1  20200101 13:45   Loc 2
1  20200101 14:00    2  20200101 15:15   Loc 1
2  20200101 15:00    2  20200101 17:30   Loc 2
2  20200101 17:00
```

To show the table as:

```
ID DateTime       Location 
---------------------------
1  20200101 12:00 Loc 1
1  20200101 13:00 Loc 2
1  20200101 14:00 Loc 2
2  20200101 15:00 Loc 1
2  20200101 17:00 Loc 2
```

Comment: Are you saying the last record (by DateTime) in `MAIN TABLE` should show the last Location (by Datetime) in Location Table? Are there ever any more than two records per ID in Location Table? Use this to check: `SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM [Location Table] GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 2`

Comment: Sorry, no. I have corrected the data. The location should show in chronological order against the DateTime in the Main Table. But occasionally, the location time can be before the Main Table DateTime at the start

Comment: It's still not clear what rule you are applying to decide whether id 1 in the final table uses Loc1 or Loc2.

Comment: Basically, the first entries should show the first location, after that, if there is a change in location, match the new location by matching the times. I'm basically trying to show where the location is for the signal in the Main Table.

Comment: So for ID 1, row two in the result, you don't care that the DateTime in `LocationTable` (13:45) was _after_ the DateTime on Main table (13:00)?

Comment: Im not explaining this very well it appears. For each ID group, the first location can be assigned to the first signal datetime entry. After that, i require the location to chronologically display and match on the hour of each entry that was made for each id grouping. If there is no hour match, use the last location entry made

Comment: _If there is no hour match, use the last location entry made_ In the sample results, ID 1, second record is Loc2. Shouldn't it be Loc 1 under this rule ? I know it sounds picky but before you or anyone can build a solution you need to specify it completely. In this situation (matching two sets of transactional data) there will be _many_ different edge cases beyond what you can see in your sample data. i.e. what if there is a Loc 3 involved at 11:59. Is it ignored?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT MAIN.ID,MAIN.DATETIME,Location.LOC
FROM MAIN
left  JOIN Location
ON Location.ID = MAIN.ID and MAIN.DATETIME=Location.DATETIME
GROUP BY Location.ID,MAIN.ID,MAIN.DATETIME,Location.LOC;
```

[image]

That is a Output Generate either change the data in your Main Table

Comment: The LOC field is completely NULL?

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. The Main DateTime and Location DateTime will rarely match, but they will match the hour (except the first entry on occasion). But i need to show the first location regardless of DateTime, and show that location in subsequent rows. If the location changes, show the change

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by using the nested **SELECT** to obtain location of nearest time that compared with the **MAIN.DATETIME**

```
SELECT MAIN.ID,MAIN.DATETIME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 B.Location
     FROM Location AS B
     WHERE B.ID = MAIN.ID
     ORDER BY CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAIN.DATETIME, B.DATETIME)>=0
                THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, MAIN.DATETIME, B.DATETIME)
                ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, B.DATETIME, MAIN.DATETIME)
     END asc) AS Location 
FROM MAIN
```

### Result :

[image]

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either. There is no join to the primary IDs.

Comment: I already update the answer by adding WHERE clause on nested SELECT to join the primary IDs

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work on the larger data set i have and is very resource intensive.

Comment: Yes, I think so. because the query is quite performance consuming.